# Disallowing PHP file to be accessed directly

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have an html form which when it gets submitted it calls a JavaScript function which by using Ajax gets information from a PHP file using post and displays it back to the page.

The question is, is it possible to make the PHP file only accessible when using the above method instead of users being able to access it directly if they go through the JS method and find it's location?

Edit: Adding a bit more information to help people out. Ajax is calling an external php file in order to update the contents of the website based on what the php file returns. Since all the Ajax calls are made in the JavaScript someone can easily find out the location and the arguments the function is using and basically call the php file directly, which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Using PHP sessions is a bit hard in this case, since I'm using Ajax I can't destroy the session once the external PHP file is done since if I do the session never renews because I'm using Ajax to update the content of the website without refreshing it.

Comment: No. The server won't know the difference, unless you have it only called after a logged-in session and use PHP's `session_start()` at the beginning.

Comment: Isn't it possible to make it harder using php sessions or something else? I don't want it to be completely fool-proof just need an extra layer of protection.

Comment: I think you could check the User-Agent. But seriously, that doesn't make it really harder. (As others stated: not possible)

Comment: Most people mentioned using php session, just wasn't sure if it possible by using the above method. User agents can be easily changed so I wouldn't want to do that. A session with random variables sounds better since it will force people to go through the source to find the random generated parts to add to the url.

Comment: @denied66, actually you don't need random variables. Just have a login page that validates the user and initiates a session. Then on the page you want protected, do a `session_start()` and see if they're logged in (by checking some value you set in the `$_SESSION` array). If the value is there, they're logged in and you can execute. Otherwise, end the script.

Comment: @denied66, gotta ask: is this really necessary? What are you trying to protect?

Comment: I'm creating a project that contains different functions, the main concert isn't that someone will find out the code (since we are talking about php that would be impossible) but I would like the service to be only accessible from the site that is hosting the project to avoid people using the php files to display the content on their websites.

Comment: Your php code is public?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with limscoder.

Here is how I use tokens on submitting forms.

1) initialize it and save it on server (when the page is loaded on the client side)

```
$token = $_SESSION['token'] = md5(uniqid(mt_rand(),true));
```

2) add it to the form

```
<input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo $token;?>" />
```

3) when submitted I check the token using

```
if(isset($_SESSION['token'], $_POST['token']) && $_SESSION['token'] == $_POST['token'])
{
//code goes here
}
```

Comment: I would add this condition `isset($_SESSION['token'], $_POST['token'])` as well :)

Comment: Yup, as both might be empty and they are equal ^^
edited, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're describing a type of [cross site request forgery](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet). The normal way of preventing this is by including a server generated token as a form value, and then validating it against a value stored in the user's session when the form is submitted. Check out the link for instructions on how to properly generate and validate the token.

Comment: Useful link, the issue is, it does not contain information on how to actually validate/compare the form token on the php side.

Comment: Generate a uuid or other random token, stick it in the user's session, include the token as a hidden form field. When the post request comes in, compare the value from the post data to the value stored in the user's session. Throw an error if they don't match.

Answer (score 0):

You can test what page called your script by checking the HTTP_REFERER (http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

BUT...it can be spoofed, so will only discourage casual attempts at getting to your data

Comment: Sadly since my main concern here is bots, I know it's quite easy in most languages to set the page referer or the agent of your requests to whatever you want, so ideally I'm looking for a different approach. Not that it will make it impossible to bypass it, but at least it should require more than just 1 line of code from their end.

Answer (score 0):

Is the html page secured? If anyone can just access the html page to call your ajax page, why bother to spend time trying to secure it. :)

However if you really need to do so, you might need to convert the html page to a php page so that you can generate a token to be placed in the form. A good token would be the sha of a secret string appended with the year, month, day and hour. When the token is sent back, use the same way to generate a test token and compare the two. This makes the token valid only for 1 hour. Of cause, in the ajax, you might need to test against last hour's token, in case the user got the form at the last minute of the hour and submits after the hour.

Edit---
If your main concern are bots then just use a captcha test.

Comment: The webpage itself it's php, the problem is, it uses Ajax to call the an external php file that contains the "core" functions. As for the captcha I personally hate them so I am trying to avoid them. The idea is just to make sure the file isn't accessible directly. If they want to go through the source to find a way to get to it then it's ok.

Comment: Anything accessible obviously the internet is difficult to secure.